# Лаги в html5 видео

Tags: видео, html5

Я добавил на сайт видео (оно доступно по ссылке http://vladit.ru/?dev=y), его проблема в том, что оно сразу начинает играть, но потом долго тупит на слабом канале.

Тем временем, видео с lending page http://1.lendpage.ru/ после паузы в несколько секунд относительно плавно играет.

Я не смог найти код паузы, я даже не смог написать подобное, потому что браузер всё равно подгружает только первую секунду. Как мне быть?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно играть видео после того, как оно подгрузится. Самое простое - атрибут preload:

```
preload="auto/metadata/none" - загружает видеофайл в проигрыватель одновременно с загрузкой веб страницы, но не воспроизводит его, по умолчанию имеет значение none  
Определения значений:  
auto - загружает видеофайл,  
metadata - загружает только служебную информацию, например: первый кадр, размеры видео, продолжительность и т.д.,  
none - не загружает видеофайл.  
Атрибут preload=" " не работает, если включен атрибут autoplay=" "
```

Comment: я ставил так, проблема в том, что загруженный интервал слишком небольшой, но больше одного кадра